# Menu function not defined

Tags: python

```
menu()

if key==1:
    print(display)    

def menu():
    while key:
        print("1- Display all data")
        print("2- Process data")
        print("press enter to Exit")
        key=input("What would u like to do?")
        return key
```

I'm keep on getting an error that `menu` is not defined.

Comment: Have you considered defining `menu` *before* trying to call it?

Comment: @jonrsharpe This is my modified code

Comment: def menu():


   while key:

       

print("1- Display all data")
       print("2- Process data")
       print("press enter to Exit")
       key=input("What would u like to do?")
       return key

menu()

if key==1:



    print(display)

Comment: ...what? What is? Please give a [mcve] with correct formatting in the question itself.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I tried what you said and now it says UnboundLocalError: local variable 'key' referenced before assignment.

Comment: Of course it does, for *exactly the reason the error message tells you*.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [function is not defined error in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5986860/function-is-not-defined-error-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're attempting to call menu before the actual definition of menu. Simply move all definitions above the block of code you use to call them, and you'll be fine.

Comment: Great, now it says UnboundLocalError: local variable 'key' referenced before assignment.

Comment: Well if you haven't defined the variable 'key', your program can't use it.