# Jupyter notebook name is not defined

Tags: python, python-2.7, api, jupyter, jupyter-notebook

First of all a disclaimer: I am using python and anaconda and jupyter all for the first time, so it might be something basic.
I pasted the following code into a new Jupyter note from this url:
https://github.com/t0pep0/btc-e.api.python/blob/master/btceapi.py

After filling in my own API and secret API key, I tried to get this running:

```
getInfo()
```

But I ran into this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-c63c8cc1259c> in <module>()
     96 
     97 
---> 98 getInfo()

NameError: name 'getInfo' is not defined
```

I checked the following solutions:

- Defining the function first and then running it, this example works
  fine in Jupyter.
  [function is not defined error in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5986860/function-is-not-defined-error-in-python)
- Defining the class first and then running the function, this example
  also works fine in Jupyter.
  [Python NameError: name is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14804084/python-nameerror-name-is-not-defined)

But since the class and function are both defined in the correct order in the script I copied, there must be something else going on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getInfo` is a class method. So you need to instanciate an `api` object before calling it. You could try something like this.

```
myApi = api()
myApi.getInfo()
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked by filling in:
`myApi = api('myApiKey', 'mySecretApiKey')`
and then running the `myApi.getInfo()`

Answer (score 1):

Some general comments, as Hakens answer is your problem. 
Don't copy this script into a cell in the notebook like this (I believe this is what you are doing) You can either manually install to site packages (there doesn't appear to be a setup script for this module), or have the file in the same directory as the notebook. Then you can run

```
from btcapi import api
```

and proceed with Haken's answer (with appropriate arguments to the **init** method)

Comment: I was indeed copying it into a cell/paragraph in a note. Being a newbie in python and jupyter, I don't get what you mean by installing to site packages... But by your second option do you mean: creating a new folder in the localhost:8888/tree, save the script as btcapi.py and then create a note in that same folder where I call the code you gave?

Comment: I tried the steps I mentioned above and got it working, thanks.